# C infinite loop when char input instead of int

Tags: c, validation, scanf, infinite-loop

I have a C program which is supposed to validate that the input from the user is an int between 1 and 8. It works if an integer is entered, but when characters are entered the validation loop repeats forever. Can you tell what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i;
  int input;
  domainEntry *myDomains = buildDomainDB();

  printf("You have the choice between the"
         " following top domains: 1-EDU, 2-COM"
         ", 3-ORG, 4-GOV, 5-MIL, 6-CN, 7-COM.CN, 8.CAN\n");
  printf("Which one do you want to pick?");
  scanf(" %d", &input);

  if(input < 1 || input > 9)
  {
    do  
    {   
      printf("Invalid input. Please try again.");
      printf("You have the choice between the"
             " following top domains: 1-EDU, 2-COM"
             ", 3-ORG, 4-GOV, 5-MIL, 6-CN, 7-COM.CN, 8.CAN\n");
      printf("Which one do you want to pick?");
      scanf(" %d", &input);

    }while((input < 1) || (input > 8));
  }
}
```

Comment: `scanf(" %d", &input);` never reads the non-numeric characters.  It remains in `stdin` for the next read.  What did you expect? Certainly a dupe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any time you are taking user-input, **you** must account for each character that remains in the input buffer (`stdin` here). This is especially true when taking input with `scanf` (or family) due to the way `scanf` handles *input* or *matching* failures. When either occurs, *no further characters are read*, and any offending characters are left in the input buffer **unread** -- just waiting to bite you again on your next attempted read (generally resulting in an infinite loop if you are taking input within a loop)

Further, you must understand how each *conversion specier* handles *leading whitespace* and whether leading whitespace is consumed by the specifier (e.g. *numeric* conversion specifiers and `"%s"`) and which do not (all others, particularly `"%c"` and `"%[...]"`).

This is one of the primary reasons a *line-oriented* function such as `fgets` (with an adequately sized buffer) or POSIX `getline` are recommended for taking user input. Both read and include the trailing `'\n'` in the buffer filled. This consumes the line completely, eliminating any uncertainty which additional characters remain in the input buffer unread. You can then pass the buffer to `sscanf` for parsing. This allows independent validation of both (1) the read ("did I get input?") and (2) the parse of information from the line ("did it contain the information I need?").

`scanf` can be used, if used correctly. This means **you** are responsible for checking the **return** of `scanf` *every time*. You must handle *three conditions*

1. `(return == EOF)` the user canceled input by generating a manual `EOF` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or on windows <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd>, but see [CTRL+Z does not generate EOF in Windows 10 (early versions)](http://proc-x.com/2017/06/ctrlz-does-not-generate-eof-in-windows-10/));
2. `(return < expected No. of conversions)` a *matching* or *input* failure occurred. For a *matching* failure you must account for every character that will be left in your input buffer. (scan forward in the input buffer reading and discarding characters until a `'\n'` or `EOF` is found); and finally
3. `(return == expected No. of conversions)` indicating a successful read -- it is then up to you to check whether the input meets any additional criteria (e.g. positive integer, positive floating-point, within a needed range, etc..).

Utilizing that with your code, you could take input in the following way -- looping continually until valid input is received or the user cancels by generating a manual `EOF`, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void empty_stdin (void) /* simple helper-function to empty stdin */
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

int main(void)
{
    int input = 0,
        rtn = 0;    /* variable to save scanf return */
    // domainEntry *myDomains = buildDomainDB();

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until valid input or EOF */
        printf ("\nSelect top level domain:\n"
                "  1-EDU\n"
                "  2-COM\n"
                "  3-ORG\n"
                "  4-GOV\n"
                "  5-MIL\n"
                "  6-CN\n"
                "  7-COM.CN\n"
                "  8.CAN\n\n"
                "choice: ");
        rtn = scanf (" %d", &input);    /* save return */

        if (rtn == EOF) {   /* user generates manual EOF */
            fputs ("(user canceled input.)\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        else if (rtn == 0) {    /* matching failure */
            fputs (" error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            empty_stdin();
        }
        else if (input < 1 || 8 < input) {  /* validate range */
            fputs (" error: integer out of range [1-8]\n", stderr);
            empty_stdin();
        }
        else {  /* good input */
            empty_stdin();
            break;
        }
    }

    printf ("\nvalid input: %d\n", input); 
}
```

(**note** the use of the helper-function `empty_stdin()` -- and that even after a successful read, you should still `empty_stdin()` to insure the input buffer is empty and prepared for the next user input -- whatever that may be)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getintmenu

Select top level domain:
  1-EDU
  2-COM
  3-ORG
  4-GOV
  5-MIL
  6-CN
  7-COM.CN
  8.CAN

choice: edu
 error: invalid integer input.

Select top level domain:
  1-EDU
  2-COM
  3-ORG
  4-GOV
  5-MIL
  6-CN
  7-COM.CN
  8.CAN

choice: 9
 error: integer out of range [1-8]

Select top level domain:
  1-EDU
  2-COM
  3-ORG
  4-GOV
  5-MIL
  6-CN
  7-COM.CN
  8.CAN

choice: 4

valid input: 4
```

If you do your job, you can successfully use `scanf` as needed.

Or, you can make your life much easier and use `fgets` and then test whether the first character in the buffer (by simply dereferencing the pointer) is a valid menu selection, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* read buffer max characters */

int main (void) {

    int input = 0;
    char buf[MAXC];
    // domainEntry *myDomains = buildDomainDB();

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until valid input or EOF */
        fputs  ("\nSelect top level domain:\n"
                "  1-EDU\n"
                "  2-COM\n"
                "  3-ORG\n"
                "  4-GOV\n"
                "  5-MIL\n"
                "  6-CN\n"
                "  7-COM.CN\n"
                "  8.CAN\n\n"
                "choice: ", stdout);
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {
            fputs ("(user canceled input.)\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }

        if (*buf < '1' || '8' < *buf) { /* check 1st char, validate range */
            fputs (" error: invalid input\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }

        input = *buf - '0';     /* convert char to integer */
        break;
    }

    printf ("\nvalid input: %d\n", input); 
}
```

Of course if a key gets stuck and the user enters more than `1023` characters -- characters will remain in the input buffer. But a simple test of whether the last character is `'\n'` and if not whether `MAXC - 1` characters were read will let you know whether that is the case. Your choice, but `fgets` provides a much easier implementation. Just remember -- *don't skimp on buffer size*. I'd rather have a buffer 10,000 bytes too long that 1-byte too short....

Answer (score 1):

this is my first time answering stackoverflow so I hope you will be able to fine it helpful.
In order to fix this error, you can just insert `getchar();` to clean the buffer after the input and it will fix the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i;
  int input;

  printf("You have the choice between the"
         " following top domains: 1-EDU, 2-COM"
         ", 3-ORG, 4-GOV, 5-MIL, 6-CN, 7-COM.CN, 8.CAN\n");
  printf("Which one do you want to pick?");
  scanf(" %d", &input);
  getchar(); //this line will clean the buffer, only fixes the error for a char input

  if(input < 1 || input > 9)
  {
    do  
    {   
      printf("Invalid input. Please try again.");
      printf("You have the choice between the"
             " following top domains: 1-EDU, 2-COM"
             ", 3-ORG, 4-GOV, 5-MIL, 6-CN, 7-COM.CN, 8.CAN\n");
      printf("Which one do you want to pick?");
      scanf(" %d", &input);
      getchar(); // will fix the error only if the input is a string, but it will duplicate the lines before..

    }while((input < 1) || (input > 8));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, in this specific chase, I would check, instead of a "number" value, the ascii table. Checking if what the user inputs, is literally a number from 1 to 9 in the ascii table. Literally, solving your problem in this case.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i;
  char input;


  printf("You have the choice between the"
         " following top domains: 1-EDU, 2-COM"
         ", 3-ORG, 4-GOV, 5-MIL, 6-CN, 7-COM.CN, 8.CAN\n");
  printf("Which one do you want to pick?");
  scanf(" %c", &input);

  if(input < '1' || input > '9')
  {
    do  
    {   
      printf("Invalid input. Please try again.");
      printf("You have the choice between the"
             " following top domains: 1-EDU, 2-COM"
             ", 3-ORG, 4-GOV, 5-MIL, 6-CN, 7-COM.CN, 8.CAN\n");
      printf("Which one do you want to pick?");
      scanf(" %d", &input);

    }while((input < '1') || (input > '8'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Avoid using *magic numbers*, at least use the ASCII characters themselves `while((input < '1') || (input > '8'))`. What happens if you accidentally enter `'a'`? How does the loop terminate then?

Comment: Oh, I did not think about that! Thank you! I'll edit it right away @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Yep, `scanf` can be a sticky-wicket. Good fix on the magic numbers, but the loop is still very fragile. Anything other than a digit in the input string and better keep your fingers on both the `Ctrl + C` keys `:)` Try it. Let you finger slip and enter `5r` instead of `5` alone and see what happens.

Comment: Wow! I am working on fixing that! It is true. I have thought on calling a "isNumber" function, but I want to try and fix it just the normal way... Thank you again @DavidC.Rankin As soon as I have it, I'll edit the answer (or delete it if I cannot find anything.

Comment: It really all boils down to the *matching failure* case. When `"%d"` encounters a non-integer, a *matching failure* occurs, reading (and extracting characters) from `stdin` stops, and any character causing the failure remains in `stdin` **unread**, just waiting to bite you again next attempted read. So you have to get rid of what is in `stdin` after a *matching failure*. (or you end up just going round-and-round-and-round the loop triggering repeated *matching failures* because the offending character is never removed from `stdin`) Ever see the movie *"Groundhog Day"?*

Comment: I have not, but I will watch it today out of curiosity. I am going to remember this day as how a firstly "simple" question cannot be answered easily by my nearly engineer graduated knowledge... Thank you. I can't seem to solve it (watching at your solution, I would have not thought about that). You were helpful! @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Well, there is really no correlation between the engineering education and C (though both require the same breadth and depth of knowledge and logic). There is no more magic to C than anything you have done in your education. C just requires the same level of understanding. It is both deceptively simple and unforgivingly exact at the same time. If you approach its learning with the same rigor, you will do just fine. There is a lot there, so it just takes time.

Answer (score 0):

As the first solution indicated, the chars remain in the buffer and you lose access to the new line to accept new values. Please find my solution below which I basically find the \n that indicates the new line to accept new input when scanf is called again

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int x;
  int result;

  while (1){
    printf("Positive Number: ");
    result = scanf("%d", &x);
    if (result == 0) {
        // find the new line to recieve new input
        while(fgetc(stdin) != '\n');
    }
    if (x>0) {
        break;
    } else {
        printf("Error, please enter a positive number.\n");
    }
 }
}
```