# Making my functions crash proof gives Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c

I am making a program that saves information about vehicles in an array made of structs and then prints it to a file. Included in the program are options to add and delete vehicles as well as printing out the saved vehicles and deleting vehicles. When choosing a vehicle to delete or print out I have to make sure the input from the user is an integer to prevent it from crashing, and if it is not an integer to give a custom error message and give the user another chance at the input. I have tried a couple of different approaches and the latest seemed promising but when running these functions I get "Segmentation fault: 11" regardless of if I input an integer or a character.

The functions seem to work just fine without the lines of code that are supposed to prevent crashing. Could someone please tell me what is causing the error or possible fixes to the problem. Thanks!

These are the functions that are causing the problem:

Function to remove vehicle:
This function takes in the array of structs as well as the int counter which counts the number of occupied spots in the array. The function then takes input from the user in the form of an int to choose which position to delete. The position can't be greater than counter or smaller than 0.

```
//Ta bort ett fordon
void del(int counter, fordon_t reg[])
{
    int pos;
    int i;
    do{
        printf("Vilken position ska tas bort?:");
        char *tmp;
        scanf("%s", tmp);
        pos = atoi(tmp);
        if (pos == 0)
        {
            printf("Var god och skriv en siffra\n");
        }
    }   
    while(pos == 0);
    if(pos<0 || pos>=counter)
    {
        printf("Ogiltig position\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=pos+1; i<counter; i++)
        {
            reg[i-1]=reg[i];
        }
        counter--;
        for(i=0; i<counter; i++)
        {
            printf("%s %d %s %s %s\n", reg[i].owner.name, reg[i].owner.age, reg[i].type, reg[i].brand, reg[i].regnum);
        }
    }
}
```

Function to print out chosen vehicle:
This function works in the same way as the previous function but instead of deleting the chosen position it prints out the information on that position.

```
//Skriv ut specifikt fordon
void print_out(int counter, fordon_t reg[])
{
    int val;
    do
    {
        char *tmp;
        printf("Vilken postition vill du se?:");
        scanf("%s", tmp);
        val = atoi(tmp);
        if (val == 0)
        {
            printf("Var god och skriv en siffra\n");
        }
    }   
    while(val == 0);
    if(val<0 || val>=counter)
    {
        printf("Ogiltig position\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s %d %s %s %s\n", reg[val].owner.name, reg[val].owner.age, reg[val].type, reg[val].brand, reg[val].regnum);
    }
}
```

If additional information about my program is needed to solve the program please tell me and I will provide more of the code.

Comment: `*char *tmp;  scanf("%s", tmp);` - you are reading into an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: `char *tmp;` is not enough. You must allocate  memory.

Comment: There's no good design reason to do `malloc` for `tmp` here. You probably want: `char tmp[100];` Or, you could just do: `scanf(" %d",&val);` and eliminate `tmp` altogether. Note that if you had compiled with warnings enabled (`-Wall`) the `scanf` would have been flagged by the compiler

Comment: Never use `atoi()` in actual code. It has zero error detection and will happily accept `atoi ("my cow");` and silently return `0` without any indication of improper input. Use `strtol()` instead or at minimum `sscanf()`. When you want specific input from a user, *loop continually* until the user provides it and `break;` when valid input is received, otherwise display error, prompt and get the next input. Handle the manual `EOF` (pressing `Ctrl+d` (`Ctrl+z` on windows)) to allow the user to cancel input.

Comment: See: [C infinite loop when char input instead of int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53059527/3422102)